# CSS How to multiple background + gradient?

Tags: html, css

I got this code from css graident generator, which is transparent at the bottom of the gradient

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,246,247,1) 0%, rgba(248,246,247,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(248,246,247,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(248,246,247,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,246,247,1) 0%,rgba(248,246,247,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,246,247,1) 0%,rgba(248,246,247,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,246,247,1) 0%,rgba(248,246,247,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(248,246,247,1) 0%,rgba(248,246,247,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f8f6f7', endColorstr='#00f8f6f7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Now I want to add a background on top of the gradient background

```
background: url('../images/letter_head.png') left top repeat-x, #f8f6f6;
```

How do I combine them both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just prepend the url of the image to each of your rules.

```
background: url(someurl), -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,246,247,1) 0%, rgba(248,246,247,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
```

Alternatively, if you don't feel like adding `url(etc)` to each of your rules, you could just specify a single `background-image` rule:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,246,247,1) 0%, rgba(248,246,247,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(248,246,247,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(248,246,247,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
...
background-image:url("someurl");
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.bg{
    width:800px; height:750px;
    background: #38BAC9 url(http://www.google.com/logos/2012/india12-hp.jpg) 10% no-repeat;
    background:url(http://www.google.com/logos/2012/india12-hp.jpg) center no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#57BEED), to(#38BAC9));
    background:url(http://www.google.com/logos/2012/india12-hp.jpg) center no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #57BEED 0%, #38BAC9 100%);    
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6kgcE/8/)**

Check this link for more information

http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/09/css-multiple-background.html